# Email attribute on all links

Tags: api, email

I'm using the API to distribute an email, the html content has links to my site. Link tracking is enabled and my links are translated into the tracking url, however when I am redirected to the target address the url contains a `%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%` parameter.

As an example if I had a link to

```
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/
```

I would eventually find my way to

```
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/?%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%
```

I haven't set this attribute so it doesn't have a value, I can confirm this by going to the properties of the email on the ExactTarget site.

How can I remove the query string parameter from my redirects?

Comment: As a work around I manually set the value of the attribute to a space, this meant the url contains a space (i.e. `%20`) rather than the `%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%` which is an improvement...

I now need to figure out how to do that programmaticaly when calling the API.

Comment: Same problem here, did you find a way to set `%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%` using the API ?

Comment: Hey @tight. It's been a while since I thought about this! Dredging my memory I didn't get any further, I don't think there was a way to set it via the API so we had to make do with the %20.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering a bit late but this parameter is added automatically by an account specific configuration (called BrandTag). You can ask your representative about it, the Services or Support Team should be able to update it to remove the value.
This is generally used for web analytics purposes (Adding tags to the each link in the email).

Comment: Hi Will, I've long left this area but your suggestion does sound like a good avenue and is probably the answer.  Hopefully someone can try it out and confirm!